# How To Login DokuWiki from my Websites?

Tags: url, dokuwiki

I want to login DokuWiki from my website by providing the URL of DokuWiki in my Website. I have mentioned the URL of DokuWiki page where I need to pass the username nad password of WIKI in the URL which I am passing in my website. My Question how to pass userename and password of Dokuwiki in the URL of my website?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand correctly, but do you want to automatically log users into the dokuwiki or link to the login page?

To link to the login page use the url http://example.com/start?do=login

To automatically login you need to use one of the Auth plugins. choose something appropritate from [this list](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugins?plugintag=authentication#extension__table).

Answer (score -1):

Dokuwiki has an experimental [XML-RPC](https://www.dokuwiki.org/devel:xmlrpc#dokuwikilogin) API which can be helpful for your used case.

To get this done, you need to enable the XML-RPC interface in `Admin -> Configuration Settings -> Authentication Settings` and put all users in `remoteuser` who will have access to make API calls.

This is an example in ruby for a dokuwiki running at `http://mydokuwiki` where I have created a user `apiuser` and password is `api_password`

```
require "xmlrpc/client"
server = XMLRPC::Client.new( "mydokuwiki","/lib/exe/xmlrpc.php")
begin
   p server.call("dokuwiki.login", "apiuser", "api_password")
rescue XMLRPC::FaultException => e
    puts "Error:"
    puts e.faultCode
    puts e.faultString
end
```

This code will return `true` if the authentication succeeds, else will return `false`